# Changing Visibility on click to hide one ImageView and appear other ImageView with delay to generate animation android widget

Tags: android, widget, imageview, refresh, delay

I need help with a Widget for Android App,

I want to animate a Refresh Button with two ImageViews. On Click the first Image should hide and the refresh button Image which is 180° degrees turned should appear. Than after small delay the 180° turned ImageView should hide again and the first ImageView should appear.

At The end I want to update the Widget.

[image]

I would be happy about better ideas to animate a refresh Button in an Android Widget. All StackoverFlow results are talking about the normal App...

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Button click event for android widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798073/button-click-event-for-android-widget)

Comment: No it doesn't because I want a delay after the ImageView was clicked. Your highlighted Ticket just talk about "onClickListener for ImageViews in Widgets".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution for my own Problem:

I created an PendingIntent to listen to the button.

```
remoteviews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.refresh_btn,
            getPendingSelfIntent(context, BTN_REFRESH));
```

---

```
protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, getClass());
    intent.setAction(action);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
}
```

---

I use global toggleState and call a method:

```
private void refresh(RemoteViews remoteviews, Context context) {
    if (toggleState) {//if Button gets clicked onReceive will update all widgets
        remoteviews.setViewVisibility(R.id.refresh_btn, View.GONE);
        remoteviews.setViewVisibility(R.id.refresh_btn_rev, View.VISIBLE);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                toggleState = false;
                updateAllWidgets(context);
            }
        }, 500);
    } else {
        remoteviews.setViewVisibility(R.id.refresh_btn, View.VISIBLE);
        remoteviews.setViewVisibility(R.id.refresh_btn_rev, View.GONE);
    }
}
```

toggleState is set to true if Button gets clicked.

Comment: alternative use viewFlipper to use more than two imageViews

Answer (score 0):

While using server call we can make progress in AsynCall as far now we can
fix it like this

```
Img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //Hide the First Image
        //Show the 2nd Img after 3 Sec 

          DelayMethod();

    }
});

public void DelayMethod(){
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            //Show the 1st Img after 3 Sec

        }
    },3000);
}
```

Comment: but I want to use it for a widget. a remote view don't have a onClickListener. Where should I implement this method and what is Img1. can you give me the code for Img1 pls ?

Comment: @CJKev img1 is the ImageView and for that you have to use DataBinding https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding

Answer (score 0):

Maybe put both images(maybe add more images with different angles to make the animation smoother) in a view flipper and then set it to `android:autoStart="true"`
`android:inAnimation="@android:anim/fade_in" android:outAnimation="@android:anim/fade_out" android:animateFirstView="true"` Then set the flipping interval as you like using `android:flipInterval="10000"`.
Then you can stop the flipping once the widget is ready.

refrence for flipping view: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9253770/15552614

Comment: it works but I don't know how to stop the view flipper programmatically.  Can you help?

Comment: @CJKev You can put a listener on the flipper's animation and then put a check inside onAnimationEnd() that if the widget is ready or not.  And if the widget is ready then simply call `viewFilpper.stopFlipping()`

Comment: @CJKev this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610106/how-to-stop-android-viewflipper-from-looping and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813108/listener-for-viewflipper-widget-flipping-events/3813179#3813179 might help.