# Android Animate Rotate

Tags: android, animation, progress-bar, customization

I did some digging in Android code, and saw the use of  in the indeterminate progress bar. after trying to create my own drawable with this tag:

```
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_pia"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:framesCount="12"
    android:frameDuration="100" />
```

I get an error:
"No resource identifier found for attribute 'frameDuration' in package 'android'" - which means that frameDuration is a private attribute. 
Is there a way to use this "animate-rotate" feature?

My task is to replace the system's default indeterminate progress bar. I'd like to do it with as little code as possible (just change few attributes if possible).
Using the ProgressBar view, setting:

```
android:indeterminateOnly="true"
android:indeterminateBehavior="cycle"
android:indeterminateDuration="3500"
android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/pia_sivuvator"
```

and point "@drawable/pia_sivuvator" to that  object would've make my task as elegant as they come but I'm stuck on those private attributes.

help?

Comment: Have the same problem. Excluding parameters (`framesCount` and `frameDuration`) does not helps much. Animation works, but does not look good for me (animation is not smooth, like a low framerate).
Created an issue on this problem http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19248

Answer (score 62):

I ran into the exact same issue.  You can exclude those parameters (framesCount and frameDuration), and it may work for you.  I tried just excluding them and it animated fine, but the width/height I was setting were not being respected, so I ended up creating a simple rotation animation and an ImageView to apply it to.  Here's the animation file (res/anim/clockwise_rotation.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:fromDegrees="0"
  android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
  android:toDegrees="360"
  android:pivotX="50%"
  android:pivotY="50%"
  android:duration="1000"
  android:startOffset="0"
/>
```

Then you just inflate your Animation, set repeat count, and start it from the View

```
Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.clockwise_rotation);
rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
myView.startAnimation(rotation);
```

Comment: use `android:repeatCount="infinite"` in the xml instead of hard code

Comment: if you want to use framesCount parameter see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760381/rotating-image-animation-list-or-animated-rotate-android/14996762#14996762

Answer (score 11):

Instead of creating an animation (more code required, not only XML configuration), use `layer-list` as drawable resource.
It is quite interesting that `layer-list` is way more fluid than `animated-rotate`.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <rotate
        android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_loading"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"/>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Then of course use it in the styles as Mario Lenci wrote:

```
<style name="YourProgressBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/progress_bar_indeterminate</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Hi, how do you make it rotate? I have an ImageView and it just shows a still drawable...thx

Comment: Animation works for me, only if I use "animated-rotate" instead of "rotate"

Answer (score 9):

I don't know how to work around the private attributes, I have the same problem.

By the way if you want to change those attributes of the ProgressBar:

```
android:indeterminateOnly="true"
android:indeterminateBehavior="cycle"
android:indeterminateDuration="3500"
android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/pia_sivuvator"
```

you can do it easily with the Styles framework defining in the `values/styles.xml` file a ProgressBar style extending the standard android one:

```
<style name="YourProgressBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar">
        <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/progress_bar_indeterminate</item>
</style>
```

and then applying it to the progress bar in the xml layout file.

```
...
<ProgressBar
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     style="@style/YourProgressBarStyle"/>
...
```

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by using this drawable xml. Although it only seems to be smooth on newer versions of Android:

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_pia"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="1080" />
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you do from this RotateDrawable? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872257/how-do-i-use-rotatedrawable