# Android - Rotate whole screen programmatically

Tags: android

I am about to leave a project and wanted to add a little Easter egg to the app. I was just wondering, is it possible to rotate the whole screen 360 degrees on a button click say? Or is this too hard?

I was potentially thinking you could take a screenshot, rotate that screenshot 360 degrees, and then delete it. But I'm not sure about the security implications of taking a screenshot the users phone

Comment: Check answer there:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359390/android-animate-rotate

Comment: So we do use this for a progress bar, but I was wondering if we were able to rotate the screen, which would mean the activity and/or fragments. So it could be anywhere in the app and essentially, grab the screen you are on, rotate it 360 degrees and allow the user to continue their journey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could specify an id in your root layout (e.g `@+id/main`) and use a classic animation like this

```
    final RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotateAnimation.setDuration(500);
    findViewById(R.id.main).startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
```

Comment: Yea this could be a good alternative to the whole screen. Thank you very much!!