# Moving a widget in android

Tags: android, android-widget, live-wallpaper, android-appwidget

I have made a digital clock as a widget using appWidgetManager in android. Now i want to move that clock on the homescreen. Please Help
Thanks!

Comment: Please mention what you have tried, your approach

Answer (score 1):

Do following steps:

1. Long press on home screen
2. Select "widget" from list
3. Select the widget you want to add from the list

The selected widget will be added to your home screen.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... but my question is not to add on the homescreen. I just want that after adding it on homescreen it should move like the case LiveWallpaper

Comment: You can refer to this question
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565023/is-there-a-way-to-animate-on-a-home-widget)