# Add animated object in background without creating a live wallpaper?

Tags: android, animation, live-wallpaper

Is there a way to add an animated object in the background of the home screen on Android? For example, an icon that would move in the background, without creating a livewallpaper to contain this special icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a home screen widget, however it is not recommended. From [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2566511/763080):

> Do not animate app widgets, unless you write you own home screen app.

More on this topic can be found on: [Is there a way to animate on a Home Widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565023/is-there-a-way-to-animate-on-a-home-widget)

Comment: Thanks. What does it mean: "your own home screen app" ? Does it mean a live wallpaper?

Comment: @Paul, no - you can create an app that replaces the default home screen. This means it organizes the layout of the icons, widgets, and controls the user sees and interacts with. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666771/how-can-i-create-a-custom-home-screen-replacement-application-for-android

Answer (score 1):

In general "no". Icon cannot move by itself. Only wallpaper as you need to provide code to do the animation.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe look into widgets. While they are not backgrounds, they can be made to behave like icons. Or more complex if that's your preference.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) and [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidWidgets/article.html) could be good places to start.